# Create hashtable/dictionary from csv data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have CSV data that looks like this:

```
label,name,value
A,foo,1
B,bar,10
C,baz,2
D,bax,4
E,bif,12
```

I've read this data in through D3's `d3.csv()` method. Now I would like to create a hash that looks like this:

```
var elems = {"foo": "A", "bar": "B", "baz": "C", ...}
```

My difficulty is I can't figure out how to loop or map through my data to create this data structure. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the result array from the `d3.csv()` is in `result`, I think the following will do what you want.

```
var elems = {};
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
{
    elems[result[i].name] = result[i].label;
}
```